# Может ли CRM сайта обращаться в 1с за получением данных из БД?

Tags: laravel, 1с, crm

Есть сайт интегрированный с 1с, и в данный момент 1с имеет возможность обращаться к сайту по апи, брать с него данные и менять их.
Я не разраб 1с поэтому хотел бы уточнить, а можно ли настроить обратную связь? Чтобы СРМ сайта обращалась в 1с, брала нужные данные и при необходимости меняла их

Comment: Возможно это глупый вопрос, но мне тяжело нагуглить информацию на эту тему и поэтому я тут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, такая возможность есть. На стороне 1С можно сделать Web (SOAP) или HTTP (REST) сервис. Выполнить публикацию на веб-сервере и всё. Можно будет обращаться с запросами в 1С.

[HTTP Сервисы: Путь к своему сервису. Часть 1](https://infostart.ru/1c/articles/842751/)

[Пример создания HTTP-сервисов на платформе "1С:Предприятие"](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/5756/hdoc)

[Работа с HTTP в 1С 8.2 и 8.3](https://1c-programmer-blog.ru/programmirovanie/rabota-s-http-v-1s-8-2-i-8-3.html)

Можно глянуть в книжку "Технологии интеграции 1С:Предприятия 8.3 (Хрусталёва)", главу первую - "Интернет-технологии". Если есть подписка ИТС, можно [тут](https://its.1c.ru/db/intgr83#content:5:hdoc)
её почитать. Либо в интернете найти.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ (:

Comment: @ВладиславГривенко, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Если тема все еще актуальна - хотел бы посоветовать более простой вариант. Чтобы избежать зависаний, лагов при получении/записи данных рекомендую {обращение к БД 1С напрямую} - НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ ! Вместо этого использовать разшаренную папку, в которую кидать текстовый/xml файл с данными для записи/получения данных из 1С; Ответ от 1С помещать также в эту папку.

На стороне 1С - проверять папку раз в N - секунд (регламентное задание)

На стороне сайта - можно проверять папку задачей в Шедулере раз в N - секунд